# Concatenate cells in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to Concatenate three cells. I want the end result to read in all numbers as the two following ways.

1. `#####-000-####`
2. `#####-###-000`

When I try to concatenate I am losing 2 zeroes. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: did #soandos not answer your question? You might mark it as such unless you still need something further

Answer (score 1):

Given that the the numbers that you want to concatentate are in A1 and B1, the following two formulas will do what you are looking for:

`=CONCATENATE(A1,"-000-",B1)`
`=CONCATENATE(A1,"-",B1,"-000")`